# How to make custom citation style in MS Word?

Tags: xml, ms-word

to make a custom citation style in MS Word I followed the instructions in this webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/create-custom-bibliography-styles

and also followed the steps in this page: https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/04/29/bibliography-citations-102-building-custom-styles/

both method didn't work, the new style don't show up in Style list in Word, I have word 2016. If there is another way to create custom style without using xsl I would like to know how.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the custom styles as well but abandoned the idea as, just like you said, the method didn't work (not even the final code samples at the end of each page).

I ended up using visual basic, as you can actually access the bibliography data this way, so you may be able to reproduce the citation behavior using VBA and content controls. (I didn't reproduce the citations but the bibliography)

To use the content controls you need to enable the developer tools in the settings.
Now, instead of actual citations, you insert content controls with titles and tags that correspond to the source you want to refer to. (E.g. give it a title like `cit_auto` and a tag corresponding to your source tag)
You need to enable the 'edit mode'(?) in the developer tools to access the properties of the controls.

Now, to access the Sources of the current document you can use `ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources`. To get ALL Sources you can use `Application.Bibliography.Sources`.

Note that `Bibliography.Sources` is a `Sources` object, and not a `Source` array.

A similar issue happens with the content controls. The function `ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle` returns a `ContentControls` object instead of a `ContentControl` array.

Both can be iterated and accessed using their indices, however you cannot pass them as parameter for their corresponding array, in case you want to modularize the code.

You can iterate the `ContentControls` in a `For Each`, select the corresponding `Source` by matching the `ContentControl.Tag` with the `Source.Field("Tag")` and set the `ContentControl.Range.Text` to the format you desire:

```
Public Sub FillSources()
    'assign variable types to get some form of autocomplete
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim src As Source
    Dim srcs As Sources

    'get sources
    Set srcs = ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources

    'iterate through the 'cit-auto' controls
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("cit_auto")
        On Error GoTo catch 'pseudo Try
        For Each src In srcs 'look for the source of the citation
            If (src.field("Tag") = cc.Tag) Then
                cc.Range.text = _ 'results in: lastname, firstname: title (day.month.year)
                    src.field("Author/b:Author/b:NameList/b:Person:b/Last") & ", " & _
                    src.field("Author/b:Author/b:NameList/b:Person:b/First") & ": " & _
                    src.field("Title") & " (" & _
                    src.field("Day") & "." & _
                    src.field("Month") & "." & _
                    src.field("Year") & ")"
                End For 'source found, skip to next control
            End If
        Next
        GoTo finally
catch:  'pseudo Catch
        Debug.Print "source " & cc.Tag & " not found"
finally:'pseudo Finally
    Next
    Debug.Print "done"
End Sub
```

Note that i didn't test this and it can probably be done better.

If the fields are missing, the Source.Field() method will throw an error and it will be skipped.
You can probably make a wrapper for the method to insert a default value in case of an error and use that to build your style.

If you need to access other fields of the source, you can look at it's `.XML` property, which contains all available data. You don't need to add the `b:`-prefix on the names of first layer of the xml, as the `.field()` method adds it automatically if it's missing.

Also i have no clue how to handle multiple authors, but maybe someone else knows.

Comment: Your :b/Last and :b/First should be /b:Last and /b:First. As for adding multiple authors, it's probably best to approach it like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-bibliographies and simply add more <b:Person> ... </b:Person> blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Word's citation & bibliography referencing relies on the use of an appropriately-coded xsl stylesheet. You cannot do it any other way unless you use a 3rd-party application such as EndNote (which may or may not support custom referencing).

Answer (score 0):

Yoy could make a copy of an existing style (`.xsl` file located at something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography\Style`) and work from there.
The first step is to change the name to properly identify it in the list of styles, so find the string `StyleName` and modify the name:

```
  <xsl:when test="b:StyleName">
    <xsl:text>APA Sixth Edition Modified by Me</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
```