# Macro to extract references out of a word document

Tags: macos, ms-word, reference, find, extract

I am a researcher where I have to work frequently with research papers containing references in following formats embedded within text

Group 1
(Sajid, 2021); or
(Sajid and Aqeel, 2021); or
(Sajid et al., 2021)

or

Group 2
Sajid (2021); or
Sajid and Aqeel (2021); or
Sajid et al. (2021)

I have a following macro that works well with first group 1 but it does not works with Group 2

```
Sub ExtractRefsFromSelection()
MsgBox ("This macro extracts references from selected text.")
Dim SearchRange As range, DestinationDoc$, SourceDoc$
DestinationDoc$ = "Refs.doc"
SourceDoc$ = ActiveDocument.Name
Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
ActiveDocument.SaveAs DestinationDoc$, wdFormatDocument
Documents(SourceDoc$).Activate
Set SearchRange = ActiveDocument.range
With SearchRange.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = "\([!\)]@[0-9]{4}\)"
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindStop
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchWildcards = True
While .Execute
Documents(DestinationDoc$).range.Text = Documents(DestinationDoc$).range.Text + SearchRange.Text
Wend
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried amending the following line

```
.Text = "\([!\)]@[0-9]{4}\)"
```

to

```
.Text = "[!\)]\(@[0-9]{4}\)"
```

but it extracts year only like (2021) only but not its authors of citations in Group 2

any help?

Comment: I don't believe there is a practical way for a Find (wildcard or otherwise) to retrieve reference data outside the parentheses. If the documents you're working with have used Word's referencing tools, you can use the tags in the citation fields to access the xml reference data and, from there, get the various source fields. See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621832/how-to-make-custom-citation-style-in-ms-word. Although the code in the link is for writing bibliography entries, the principles are the same for reading them.

Comment: I tried to use a wildcard to separate like 10 or 20 letters (anyone) coming before the parenthesis regardless of author's name or citation style. Then I can do a little work to exact citation and delete extra words like ................. g to Sajid and Aqeel (1971)... here I can delete "g to" later to separate the reference. But no success other than the I can separate the citation year.

Answer (score 0):

If the documents you're working with have used Word's referencing tools, you can replicate the references then insert the full details of each citation, with the author/editor details. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, Fld As Field, i As Long
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument: Set DocTgt = Documents.Add
With DocSrc
  With .Bibliography
    For i = 1 To .Sources.Count
      DocTgt.Bibliography.Sources.Add .Sources(i).XML
    Next
  End With
  For Each Fld In .Fields
    With Fld
      If .Type = wdFieldCitation Then
        With DocTgt
          .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
          .Fields.Add .Paragraphs.Last.Range, wdFieldEmpty, Replace(Fld.Code.Text, "\n", ""), False
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```